# How to print data from a module used in my fortran subroutine

Tags: fortran

Thanks for the help in advance..
Kindly I want to print data in an output file of the main FORTRAN program and these data defined in a module and I already declare using that module in the main program. but I couldn't get the write statements neither in the main program nor in the module.

```
MODULE model 
IMPLICIT NONE
 SUBROUTINE model_initialize 
 IMPLICIT NONE
 INTEGER a,dim REAL(float) :: E,nu 
 REAL(float) :: lambda,mu 
 E=5000 lambda = E*nu/(1.d0+nu)/(1.d0-2.d0*nu) 
 mu = E/2.d0/(1.d0+nu) 
 RETURN 
 END SUBROUTINE model_initialize 
 Write (6,)'Lambda',lambda 
 Write (6,)'mu',mu 
 END MODULE model 
 SUBROUTINE XXXX 
 USE model 
 IMPLICIT NONE 
 CALL model_initialize 
 Write (6,)'Lambda',lambda 
 Write (6,)'mu',mu 
 END SUBROUTINE XXX
```

When I put the write statements in the module or in the main subroutine , I cant see them in the output.

Many thanks for the help
Msekh

Comment: Are you opening an output file?  Do you open it in your module subroutine or main routine?

Comment: Thanks for the question, I wanted to print the values of a parameter in the module in my main subroutine XXX but the didn't appear and also tried to write these values by putting the write statement in the module it self but also wasn't possible

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand what the problem is.  Why wasn't it possible to write the value from the main routine?  Does the example code in the answer below by mgilson not work for you?

Comment: Perhaps the confusion is elsewhere... what exactly do you mean by "main subroutine"? Subroutines are not executed automatically, only the (main) `program` is. Mgilson's example should therefore work. Also, you cannot have a `write` statement in a module unless it is contained in a subroutine or function; a module does not execute anything itself either.

Comment: Thanks Matt and sigma, I'm sorry if the question is not so clear. the issue is, I want to write data from a module used in the main program, when i put the write statement in the module or in the main program I can't see the write statements results and I do the following:

Comment: MODULE model
IMPLICIT NONE
SUBROUTINE model_initialize
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER a,dim
REAL(float) :: E,nu
REAL(float) :: lambda,mu
E=5000
lambda = E*nu/(1.d0+nu)/(1.d0-2.d0*nu)
mu = E/2.d0/(1.d0+nu)
RETURN
END SUBROUTINE model_initialize
Write (6,*)'Lambda',lambda
Write (6,*)'mu',mu
END MODULE model
------------

SUBROUTINE XXXX
USE model
IMPLICIT NONE
CALL model_initialize
Write (6,*)'Lambda',lambda
Write (6,*)'mu',mu
END SUBROUTINE XXXX

Comment: wow that's hard to read.  Why "write(6,)", shouldn't that be "write(6,*)" (I'm not sure if that's equivalent, I've never seen the former syntax.)   I'm not sure though, that should work.  That said, I've seen cases where write()s in a function don't work, but they always work in subroutines. :S

Comment: @Math, Thanks for reply. I put 6 in the write statement to get the output in that file of ABAQUS software that I want to run this subroutine in it. I posted it again and hoping it is clear in reading now.. Best regards

Comment: I have changed the post to be more clear.. best regards to all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mgilson has already provided you with an example that should work, but the code you posted will not compile. This is why:

- Your subroutine `model_initialize` is in the "specification part" of your module. It should either be external (like `xxxx`) or internal to the module (in which case you have to provide a `contains` statement).
- The variables in `model_initialize` are local to the subroutine and will not be accessible outside it.
- You cannot have executable code (like `write`) in the specification part of a module, only in internal procedures.
- `float` is not a native Fortran kind, you have to use the numerical parameters (usually 4, 8, 16), define your own, or use the definitions in the `iso_fortran_env` module.

That said, if you only need to define some data you want to make accessible, you can simply put that directly in the module like this:

```
module model
  use iso_fortran_env 
  implicit none

  integer :: A, dim 
  real(real32) :: E, nu, lambda, mu

  E = 5000
  lambda = E*nu/(1.d0+nu)/(1.d0-2.d0*nu)   ! <-- nu is undefined
  mu = E/2.d0/(1.d0+nu)

contains

  subroutine xxxx 
    write (6,*) 'lambda', lambda 
    write (6,*) 'mu', mu 
  end subroutine xxxx
end module model
```

Answer (score 1):

do you mean something like:

```
module material
  real :: stress = 6.0
  save
end module material

subroutine xxx()
  use material, only: stress
  write(6,*) stress
end subroutine

program main
call xxx()
end program main
```

This will write the value of stress to the file-like object connected with unit 6 (usually this is stdout, but it might create a new file called `fort.6` depending on compiler and environment settings).

Comment: This is quite tough to read.  You'll need to edit your original question putting this into the body of the question.